# How to assign enum to variable

Tags: c#, .net

How to assign new variable from declared enum

```
public enum FontStyle
{
 Regular = 0;
 Bold =1;
 Italic = 2
}
// dont know what Type to cast it :/
TYPE fontstyle = FontStyle.Bold;
```

I am not sure which TYPE to cast it, It is contained within System.Drawing class.

Comment: `FontStyle  fontstyle = FontStyle.Bold`

Comment: @Dshah are you sure? it doesn't work or some other code of yours doesn't work?

Comment: it is the same code, I am getting this error "Embedded statement cannot be a declaration or labeled statement"

Comment: @I4V - :) "maybe it is lazy" should be in FAQ as answer "why it does not work" question!

Comment: [This is the compiler error you're getting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/xaw06638%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). Notice anything in the description that matches what you're doing? I can only spot the semicolons in your `enum` declaration that should be commas but you're obviously not telling enough to pinpoint the problem here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's of type `FontStyle` i.e. Enums are first class types.

```
public enum FontStyle
{
    Regular = 0;
    Bold =1;
    Italic = 2
}

// No need to cast it
FontStyle fontstyle = FontStyle.Bold;
```

Edit: Perhaps you have code like this:

```
if(1 == 1)
    FontStyle fontstyle = FontStyle.Bold;
```

for your error (*Embedded statement cannot be a declaration or labeled statement*) surround your code in a block statement e.g.

```
if(1 == 1)
{
    FontStyle fontstyle = FontStyle.Bold;    
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Enums *are* types, so your variable should be of the type `FontStyle`:

```
FontStyle fontstyle = FontStyle.Bold;
```

Comment: Thanks but I am getting this error when used above  Embedded statement cannot be a declaration or labeled statement

Comment: @Dshah: I'll bet a dollar you are trying to do `if (x) FontStyle f = whatever;` which is not legal because *where could you then use `f`?*  You have to instead either say `FontStyle f = 0; if (x) f = whatever;` or `if (x) { FontStyle f = whatever; ... use f here ... }`.  More generally, **you will get better results here if you tell people what error you are getting rather than saying "it doesn't work"**. Help the people who are trying to help you by including relevant details in your question.

Comment: I am sorry  but I did not know if it was due to  if statement. I was going to post now full code/error details but while writing I noticed Plymouth223 reply and added braces around my code. Thanks for the help though I owe you a dollar

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you use `,` to separate enum elements, not `;` ...
like

```
enum Days {Sat, Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri};
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you don't have a class vs property name mixing in your code...

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // dont know what Type to cast it :/
        System.Drawing.FontStyle fontstyle = FontStyle.Bold;
        MessageBox.Show(fontstyle.ToString());
    }
```

returns "Bold" :)...

Make sure to have

using System.Drawing;

and that you don't have the enum declared in the same location where you said you cannot create the enum object.