# How can I assign an enum to a variable?

Tags: c#, enums, variable-assignment

I want to simplify my references to an enum:

```
class Order
{
    enum OrderStatus{open,cancelled, onHold}
}
```

with something equivalent to this:

```
class SomeOtherClass
{
    // assign enum to a simpler name
    enum Status = Order.OrderStatus

    public void foo(){
        // so the reference is simpler, rather than Order.OrderStatus.open
        Console.Write(Status.open);
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Comment: Move the `enum` out of `class Order`?

Comment: Use the enum's type as the variable's type..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to assign enum to variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18453906/how-to-assign-enum-to-variable)

Answer (score 0):

You could place this statement at the top of your source code file.

```
using Status = Order.OrderStatus;
```

**Beware** if you have declared your `Order` class in a namespace called for instance `ConsoleApplication`, you have to prep-end this before Order.

```
using Status = ConsoleApplication.Order.OrderStatus;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use alias directives to make this a little bit shorter. This needs to be written in the same namespace that has your SomeOtherClass.

```
using OrderStatus = Order.OrderStatus;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you must make the enum public, so it is visible outside the class:

```
class Order
{
    public enum OrderStatus { open, cancelled, onHold }
}
```

Then you can assign it an alias for simpler access

```
// give an alias
using Status = Order.OrderStatus;

class SomeOtherClass
{
    public void foo(){
        // reference is now simpler, rather than Order.OrderStatus.open
        Console.Write(Status.open);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use Enum as extra and use/reuse it everywhere your need like this:

```
public enum OrderStatus 
{ 
   open, 
   cancelled, 
   onHold 
}

class SomeOtherClass
{
    private OrderStatus Status;

    public void foo(){
        // so the reference is simpler, rather than Order.OrderStatus.open
        Console.Write(Status.open);
    }
}
```

If the Order is part of the "SomeOtherClass" and is relevant here please forward it in the constructor and make valid for the workflow in the foo() method.